# Pass data to service - android?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-asynctask, android-service

I have an AsyncTask in my Activity,I call AsyncTask :

```
CallServicesSetQuestion task = new CallServicesSetQuestion();
task.execute(rb);
```

Then :

```
public class CallServicesSetQuestion extends AsyncTask<RequestPackage,String,String>{

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(RequestPackage... params) {
        Intent response = new Intent(_Context, SendComment_Service.class);
        response.putExtra("params", params[0]);<===== HERE
        _Context.startService(response);


        return content;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
}
```

I need to send RequestPackage to service but I can't.How I can't send it.

Here is my RequestPackage :

```
public class RequestPackage {
    private String uri;
    private String method = "GET";
    private Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();

    public String getUri() {
        return uri;
    }

    public void setUri(String uri) {
        this.uri = uri;
    }

    public String getMethod() {
        return method;
    }

    public void setMethod(String method) {
        this.method = method;
    }

    public Map<String, String> getParams() {
        return params;
    }

    public void setParams(Map<String, String> params) {
        this.params = params;
    }

    public void setParam(String key,String value){
        params.put(key,value);
    }
    public String getEncodedParams(){
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (String key:params.keySet()) {
            String value = null;
            try {
                value = URLEncoder.encode(params.get(key),"UTF-8");
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (sb.length()>0){
                sb.append("&");
            }
            sb.append(key + "=" + value);
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Here response.putExtra("params", params[0]); I can't send RequestPackage to service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make Request Package Serializable or parseable Like this then you can send

```
public class RequestPackage implements Serializable
 {
    private String uri;
    private String method = "GET";
    private Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();

    public String getUri() {
        return uri;
    }

    public void setUri(String uri) {
        this.uri = uri;
    }

    public String getMethod() {
        return method;
    }

    public void setMethod(String method) {
        this.method = method;
    }

    public Map<String, String> getParams() {
        return params;
    }

    public void setParams(Map<String, String> params) {
        this.params = params;
    }

    public void setParam(String key,String value){
        params.put(key,value);
    }
    public String getEncodedParams(){
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (String key:params.keySet()) {
            String value = null;
            try {
                value = URLEncoder.encode(params.get(key),"UTF-8");
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (sb.length()>0){
                sb.append("&");
            }
            sb.append(key + "=" + value);
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: How I can get data from service?

Comment: You can use Handler for get data from service

Comment: Thanks a lot .With your guide I use from this link https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2014/01/android-tutorial-two-methods-of-passing-object-by-intent-serializableparcelable.html.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to pass it Serialized

```
public class RequestPackage implements Serializable { .. }


Intent response = new Intent(_Context, SendComment_Service.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putSerializable("params", params[0]);
response.putExtras(bundle);
_Context.startService(response);
```